# How can I create this pop-up dialog in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohnr9.png

This is the dialog that appears when you right-click a bookmark and choose 'edit'. I'd like to create something in similar style (has multiple fields for user input) for a chrome extension I'm creating, but I can't even figure out what it's called, let alone how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the Chrome Bookmark Edit Dialog. To perform similar actions to that dialog in your extension, you'll need to use the `chrome.bookmarks` api.  Here's the full documentation on that api: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html.

Start by requesting bookmarks permissions in your `manifest.json` and go from there:

```
"name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: no, no -- I want to create a dialog box that uses that style, but serves a different purpose. when I search for javascript dialog boxes, I only get alerts and prompts; I want something with multiple fields for user input. the Chrome Bookmark Edit Dialog was just an example

Comment: Well, with a Chrome Extension you can create popups from Browser Actions (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups) or from Page Actions (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#method-setPopup).  You can't create that native looking dialog with the Chrome Extension, though you can style your `popup.html` to look however you want.

Comment: I don't want it to be a popup from clicking the browser action, it should appear when the user selects something from a context menu. I guess I can still create a popup -- I just would have preferred not to have a separate html file.